# Python array fill optimisation

Tags: python, numpy

I have a color array like this:

```
colors = [
            [50, 0, 255],  # Blue
            [255, 0, 0],    # Red
            [255, 0, 180],  # Pink
            [255, 140, 0],  # Orange
            [255, 255, 0],  # Jaune
            [0, 255, 255],  # Cyan
        ]
```

I have a big pixels array:

```
pixels = [0] * width * height * 3
```

I want to build an image which contains random blocks of the same color:

```
    for y in range(block_count_y):
        for x in range(block_count_x):
            color = random.choice(colors)

            for yp in range(block_height):
                for xp in range(block_width):
                    offset = (y * width * block_height + yp * width + x * block_width + xp) * 3
                    pixels[offset + 0] = color[0]
                    pixels[offset + 1] = color[1]
                    pixels[offset + 2] = color[2]
```

Then i have to get bytes pixels with this:

```
bytes(pixels)
```

My loops are very slow. I am looking for a way to optimize this.

I have tried numpy and list comprehension but it does not work...

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: What are the `block_count_XY` variables supposed to mean? Are you sure you're supposed to be looping over them independently, rather than `zip`ing them together to get matched pairs? Can you show your attempt at using numpy, as it's broadcasting seems like it could handle this very easily: `pixels_arr[y:y+block_height,x:x+block_width,:] = color`

Comment: This variables contains the number of blocks